# C# - Running 40 Foreach Iterations takes 5 seconds

Tags: c#, mongodb, foreach, mongodb-.net-driver

This code below takes 5 seconds for 40 iterations. I do NOT think this has anything to do with MongoDb, as the filters should build instantaneously and the call should just be made here, NOT awaited. Please let me know if you see anything that would take more than a 1000th of a second per iteration here:

```
//There are 40 categories
foreach (var category in categories)
{
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.In("CurrentOfficeId", officesIds)
            & Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("CategoryId", category.Id);

if (userId > 0) filter &= Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("SubmittedById", userId);

pendingCallsForItemCountPerCatArray[numberOfCatBeingIterated] = mongoItemsCollection
                                                                    .Find(filter)
                                                                    .CountAsync();
}
```

Edit: Note that I am trying to make every call before the previous call completes. Otherwise the code would be as follows:

```
callResult[numberOfCatBeingIterated] = await mongoItemsCollection
```

edit 2: I confirmed that the call is generating a `Task<long>`, rather than a long. I also confirmed that commenting out the call drops the iteration to 0 seconds, which we knew, but I am just confirming.

Comment: could you show us indexes on this collection?

Comment: Wait, am I missing something? My understanding is that I am NOT waiting for the call to complete before making the next call. Just MAKING the calls  shouldn't take this long...right? If indexes are coming into play,the code is not doing what I want it to - I wait for call results later, at which point I would worry about indexes and call completion times.

Comment: Houston we have a problem -> it looks like we need to address this on mongo driver side :(

Comment: Have you tried changing your call to just: `mongoItemsCollection.CountAsync(filter)`

Comment: That was it, I didn't even consider the obvious, sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: mongo jira entry for driver issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1589

Comment: @VSO - could you check this mongo-jira issue (in my previous comment ) and respond with requested details?

Comment: @professor79: Hey, sorry for slow reply, I wasn't on SO yesterday afternoon. With that said, are you confusing me with someone or is this in reference to an earlier question? If so, please link (I did follow the SO link in the jira issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be because you're always iterating through the mongoItemsCollection with the .Find(filter) ?

Comment: I would suspect this is on the right track.  Is there a `FindAsync` option?

Comment: There is a find async option. But then I would bring all the items back.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever code is "taking long time" to execute - it is a good reason to see what is under the hood in mongoDB :-).

1. set mongo in profiler mode

> db.setProfilingLevel(2,20)

2. then check what was going there

> db.system.profile.find().limit(100).sort( { ts : -1 } ).pretty()

3. when finished

> db.setProfilingLevel(0)

As there is 40 calls at once 125 ms/per call looks pretty good (imagine that you have a lock during each query)

Comment: I am trying to run the queries async though - so they should all be made fairly quickly, EVEN if the first query takes 15 minutes to complete (hypothetically). Edit: I see what you are saying, and I appreciate your answer, profiling is very helpful, but I don't think that's the problem here. (And yes, I know I could create more efficient indexes with profiling because sometimes the mongo driver doesn't generate the query you would expect).

Comment: try to use Parallel.ForEach() insted as you are still waiting to get data on last step

Comment: I will try it, but I don't understand how I am still waiting for data (could be a gap in my understanding when I do Tast<type> myPendingTask = asyncMethod, rather than type myCallResult = await asyncMethod.

Comment: @professor79: Updated my question - still messing with it though.

Comment: because db engine has 40 requests at once and they can block each other?
Did you try to execute same query on mongoDB console with explain? - to get insight how it is executed (FETCH IXSCAN) ?

Comment: ty for your help, looks like I just missed the obvious though.